# Can I use the phrase “Something survives us”, and if I can, could it have two meanings?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning, difference, phrase-usage

> One day, when the human species will have disappeared, Nature will have shown that **she**, in fact, **survives us**.

I believe I can use this phrasing to mean both;

- That nature **survives/lives longer** than us.
- The nature **survives despite ‘us’**.

However, I’m unsure and would like to know if I’m correct and if not, why not.

Edit:: I would like to use the ambiguity in a prose poem. Apologies if this is the wrong forum to ask a question for this purpose.

Comment: Unless you want to use the present tense for dramatic effect, you would need a future tense. But it's unclear what the sentences are supposed to mean, for example "The fountain survived the refurbishment".

Comment: Are you, perhaps, thinking of the idiom "{someone} is survived by {family members}"  Otherwise (which you might rarely see in active form "His wife survived him")

Comment: For the second case I am considering a sentence like;

> One day, when the human species will have disappeared, Nature will have shown that she, in fact, survives us.

[See this example] (https://peoolsson.se/text/shadowsofmodernity/)

And now, thinking about it, I suppose one implies the other.

Comment: Who will Nature show that fact to?

Comment: [Survive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/survive) has various meanings including to outlive or live through something, and to live/prosper despite something. "Subject survives us" is a bit too vague with no context. But with the additional context it provides "One day, when the human species will have disappeared, Nature will have shown that she, in fact, survives us" is OK (although I might prefer "will survive us" or "can survive us"). It's technically ambiguous because it could mean "nature outlives us" or "nature lives despite our actions", but that's OK.

Comment: You should put your longer example sentence in the original question.

Comment: I think "survived" sounds more natural, as in: "she, in fact, survived us".  You really should put your longer example sentence in the original question, because as a stand-alone sentence with no context, "Subject survives us" seems very wrong.  It's using the present tense, but implying that at this moment, "us" have died.  So then, who is speaking?

Comment: nature does not take "the". It would only do so with a different meaning: The nature of the crime was so hideous that [x happened]. However, the phrase does not say **despite us**, that is just the mental addition to it someone might make. But  you can say that of course: Nature survives despite us.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is *yes* - it's perfectly idiomatic to say something will survive, or has survived something else. It's essentially a synonym of 'outlive':

> He is survived by his wife and four children.

But there are couple of unusual things about your example.

Firstly, you're saying it about *nature*. The personification of nature isn't unusual in itself - we talk of 'mother nature', which you likely know as you've used the common female pronoun. But it may be unusual to some to suggest that nature itself can outlive humanity, because 'nature' is somewhat abstract in that its boundaries are not easily defined. Do you just mean the planet? Its ecosystem? Other animal and plant life? Or the universe, which is also subject to the laws of 'nature'? You could perhaps use the wider context to make that clear.

Secondly, you say that, once we are gone, nature will have "*shown us*". Who, is '*us*'? It can't be humanity, because we're all gone.